# Creating login screen in labview

Tags: labview

I am trying to create a login screen. It takes username and password. Also, I create a text file, I write valid usernames and passwords in to the text file.

When I press the `confirm button` (after I enter the user name and password in to the login screen), program matches the username and password, if they are valid then led light open.

It works but when I try to press the `confirm button` more than 2 times, it fails. Actually not give an error but confirm button blocked so, I can not make trial more than 2. What are the possible reasons for that?

**Here is the my vi:**
[image: here is the my vi]

Comment: Even for programs that are not very important you should not store credentials as plain text in a file named ´login.txt´. This makes the login process kind of obsolete...

Comment: If the OK button is becoming unresponsive it sounds as if the inner While loop isn't exiting. Have you tested what's happening using probes and/or execution highlighting? It's not clear from your image but it looks as if the stop terminal of this loop will only get a True value if the user name and password match values in the file, otherwise it will loop indefinitely. If you could post a VI snippet instead of a plain image we could check this for you.

Comment: As nekomatic mentioned, the inner while loop is not exiting. This happens because your while loop only exits when it finds a matching username and password. You need additional logic on the regex such that if you read through the file and haven't found it, the loop exits. There are many ways to do this, my preferred one involves a shift register. As Kaspar said, you need to be hashing the password with something like SHA2 or AES, both of which have libraries in LV. Make sure your password is displaying as such by right clicking it and selecting the 'Password' display mode. Also close the file.

Answer (score 1):

Move all the code of the case structure inside the event case. Whenever there is a click event the code inside the case structure will be executed. Hence, there is no need to wire the Boolean from the OK button to outside the event case.

**OK event:**
[image: "OK event"]

Also, I would have a stop case with a stop button to end the while loop.

**Stop event:**
[image: "Stop event"]

Comment: This answer doesn't explain the problem described in the question, and if my guess as to what's causing the problem is correct (i.e. the inner while loop isn't exiting) then it wouldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From your code example it looks like the first time the confirm button is pressed the case structure will run. In a While loop the user name and password are checked against the text file and if both match the LED indicator is set to true and the while loop is stopped. If either user name or password do not match the text file data then the LED will stay off and the loop would continue, blocking the confirm button from triggering again.

Looking further at the function of your code, the feedback node will retain the previous value so the second time the confirm button is pressed the username and passwords are checked from the entry following the last found entry. If the new username is before or the same then it will not be found so will enter an endless loop as in the previous case.

To resolve this you should look at:

1. the initialiser terminal for the feedback node is only used for the first time the vi is executed, if it is inside a loop then it will not have any effect on subsequent execution. You should remove it and modify your code to ensure the complete file is checked each time. Maybe try using a shift register terminal on the edge of the while loop and wire through to the far side of the loop.
2. look at the case when the username and passwords do not match to prevent an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is an inherent logical problem with the code that nobody has addressed yet, which is leading to the failure.

As many others have pointed out, your inner while loop is not exiting. It appears that the case statement in the inner while loop is always true, as you tied it to the Boolean constant `TRUE`. Your code will enter that case statement, and if either your username or password are incorrect, your `AND` will result in false. The indicator will not change, but you also do not stop the loop. In order to read in new values, you must stop the inner while loop.

Answer (score -1):

The question seems to have been answered by other users so I just wanted to add my two cents from having just implemented something very similar myself. We needed to secure the information in the username and password file to prevent/detect tampering. Towards this end we used the built in MD5 function in labivew to create a hash of the password and then computed the hash of the user input with the hash stored in the file.

Further, to prevent people from recomputing the hash and inserting it in the file we took the row of data and computed a hash of the row elements and placed that in the file as well so the system could determine if the row hash matched and identify any tampering.

Additionally we salted our hash with a string so that even if the user knew what information was used to compute the hash they would still have to know how the string in question was salted to be able to generate the proper checksums. Perhaps this is overkill for your uses but, since the question seems to have been answered, I figured I'd throw this out for you to consider.